# How to make a full height side menu?

Tags: html, css

Hi people I had this code:

```
  <div id="admin-left-menu">
    <div class="admin-menu-title"><center><span>HI</span>PEOPLE</center></div>
    <div class="admin-menu-avatar">

    <center><img src="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/236x/9a/ff/c4/9affc464003b8c06bd7b0f478da8ce4c.jpg"></center>


    <?=$_SESSION['username']?>

    <br>
    <br>

</div>


    <div class="division-disabled">Geral</div>
    <div class="division-checked"><a href="javascript:window.location.href=window.location.href">Página Inicial</a></div>
        <div class="division"><a href="references.php">Referencias</a></div>
    <div class="division"><a href="banners.php">Banners</a></div>
    <div class="division"><a href="advertising.php">Publicidade</a></div>
    <div class="division-disabled">Zona de trabalho</div>
    <div class="division"><a href="games.php">Jogos</a></div>
    <div class="division"><a href="channels.php">Canais</a></div>
    <div class="division"><a href="films.php">Filmes</a></div>
    <div class="division-disabled">Ferramentas</div>
    <div class="division"><a href="userlist.php">Lista de users</a></div>
    <div class="division"><a href="adduser.php">Adc. user manualmente</a></div>


    </div>
```

and when I have a big list the sidebar don't work correctly.

My css code here:

```
 #admin-left-menu {width: 208px; background: #33414E; height: 100%; position:absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px;}
.admin-menu-title{height: 39px; width: 208px; background: #CE9715; color: #FFFFFF; font-size:15px; padding: 16px 0px 0px 0px;}
.admin-menu-title span{font-weight:none !important; color: #111111;}
.admin-menu-avatar {width: 208px; height: 160px; border-bottom: 1px solid #273541; border-top: 1px solid #273541; background: #2D3945; color: #FFFFFF; text-align:center; font-size: 11px;}
.admin-menu-avatar img{width: 80px; height: 80px; border-radius: 100%; margin:20px 0px 9px 0px;}
.admin-menu-role {margin: -12px 0px 0px 0px; color: #CE9715;}

.division-disabled{padding: 17px; font-size: 11px; color: #AAAAAA; border-bottom: 1px solid #273541}
.division-checked{padding: 17px 32px; font-size: 11px; border-bottom: 1px solid #273541;}
.division-checked a{ text-decoration: none;  color: #CE9715;}
.division{padding: 17px 32px; font-size: 11px; color: rgb(170, 170, 170); border-bottom: 1px solid #273541;}
.division a{ text-decoration: none; color: #FFFFFF;}
.division a:hover{color: #CE9715; -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-out; -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-out; -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-out; -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-out; transition: all 0.4s ease-out;}
```

Anyone can help me? To solve the height (%) or put scroll ..

I'm trying many ways but the result it's:

http://prntscr.com/5sklur

Comment: Use bootstrap. (http://getbootstrap.com/)

Comment: The problem is that I do not really want to use the bootstrap

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `height` to `min-height` in the `#admin-left-menu` rule

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/5zgt29hg/1/

Answer (score 0):

At first, I didn't see what your problem was cause I wasn't experiencing the same thing when I loaded your page up; however, upon shrinking my browser, I saw what you were seeing.

To fix it, in #admin-left-menu style, I simply changed the ***height*** attribute to to "**auto**", instead of "100%"

Hope this helps!